# Change CSS Class of Button Using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, css

Is it possible to change the CSS class of an HTML button using JavaScript?

I tried this but it didn't work:

```
document.getElementById("btnChoice1").setAttribute("class", "redButton");
```

HTML Button

```
<button class="basicButton" id="btnChoice1">
```

CSS

```
.basicButton {
    width:300px;
}

.redButton {
    width:300px;
    background-color:red;
}
```

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/195951/change-an-elements-css-class-with-javascript

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`className` is preferred but your `setAttribute()` code should work. If it's not working then you probably have the Javascript executing before the button exists on the page.

Check that the code is within an `window.onload` event or is after the button markup.

Answer (score 3):

Try `document.getElementById("btnChoice1").className = 'redButton'`.

Answer (score 2):

you could try it with this code:

```
document.getElementById("btnChoice1").className = "redButton";
```

if you want to use jquery you have to write it like this:

```
(document.getElementById("btnChoice1")).setAttribute("class", "redButton");
```

Greets Knerd

Answer (score 0):

Your code works.

You probbably didn't put the javascript where it should be or you have some error in your code so javascript doesn't execute.

```
<button id="change" onClick="document.getElementById('btnChoice1').setAttribute('class', 'redButton');">change</button>

<button class="basicButton" id="btnChoice1">
    test
</button>
```

​

Proof that your code is working here http://jsfiddle.net/nDmKP/